# Load XML held in a string to a Data Grid

Tags: c#, xml, datagrid

I'm pulling XML from a web service.    I've loaded the returned data to a string with

```
HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
StreamReader loResponseStream =
new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), enc);
string Response = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
```

What's the best way to get this into a DataGrid named AccountList.   This DG is on a WPF form.

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Desktop and c#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you having any problems in particular? Are you using DataBindings?

Comment: I tried to set a datasource but this isn't accessible. I only see datacontext

Answer (score 0):

parse XML to a list then bind to it.
Just as an example, lets pretend your `XML` is something like this (I know this is a simple example, if you have a complex xml structure you need to put more work into deserializing it (build supporting classes, so you can add then in to a list):

```
<Items>
   <Item>a</Item>
   <Item>b</Item>
   <Item>c</Item>
</Items>
```

lets assume you have a property that you bind to:

```
//could be of some <T> but for simplicity..
ObservableCollection<string> MyItems {get;set;}
```

parse XML and sign it to your property  let the binding do the rest:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(Response);
var list = doc.Root.Elements("Item").Select(element => element.Value).ToList();

MyItems.Clear();
foreach(var item in list)
    MyItems.Add(item);
```

well, and your binding in `XAML` should be :

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
```

Comment: Thanks Denis. This is a big help